# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

I am getting this error when using `copy_object` method of boto3 when running my Python code in AWS Lambda.

**AWS Lambda Code**

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    some_binary_data = b'Here we have some data'
    client = boto3.client("s3")

    # Upload - Working
    client.put_object(Body=some_binary_data, Bucket='test', Key="upload/binary_1.txt")
    
    # Copy - Working
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': 'test',
        'Key': 'upload/binary_1.txt'
    }
    s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'test', 'upload/binary_1_copied.txt')

    # Copy - NOT WORKING  
    # Access Denied even after adding GetObjectTagging and PutObjectTagging permissions in the policy

    client.copy_object(Bucket="test", CopySource="upload/binary_1.txt", Key="upload/binary_1_copied.txt")

    # Delete - Working
    client.delete_object(Bucket="test", Key="upload/binary_1.txt")
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

I am using this policy (mentioned as JSON) for the role assigned to my lambda function.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ReplicateObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectTagging",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:PutObjectTagging",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::test/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::test"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```

Note - S3-Bucket currently contains upload/binary_1.txt file

Comment: I guess `test` is not actual name of your bucket?

Comment: Yes it `test` the actual name of my s3 bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `test` is the actual bucket name that you can't use it. Bucket names must be **unique** accross all AWS accounts and regions. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html):

> An Amazon S3 bucket name is **globally unique**, and the namespace is shared by all AWS accounts. This means that after a bucket is created, the name of that bucket cannot be used by another AWS account in any AWS Region until the bucket is deleted.

So you get **access denied** because `test` bucket belongs to someone else. You have to ensure that your bucket names are unique and not used by anyone else.